# Base SDK Missing, CFNetwort.framework not listed

Tags: iphone, xcode, asihttprequest

HEllo,
I have just installed xcode 3.2.3 and SDK4. I need to use ASIHttpRequest and then follow the instruction setup for this.
I need to add several frameworks and lib (as described here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions but I cannot find CFNetwork in the list.
xcode only shows "Base SDK Missing" in the list where we should be able to select among the device / simulator, I guess this might be an explanation... ?
I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks,
Luc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your project in Xcode, Get Info, change the Base SDK to iPhone Device 4.0.

You'll probably want to change the iPhone OS Deployment Target in Build settings, too. The 4.0 SDK can be used to build apps compatible with iPhones back several versions.

Comment: Hello, ok done. So, there is normally no risk, when developping an app for OS4 that it's not compatible with the previous versions ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Comment: I wouldn't say no risk, but Apple developers seem to think it's less risky than using a previous SDK with Xcode 3.2.3. Only SDK 4 has been qualified for Xcode 3.2.3.

To be backward compatible, you'll need to use 4.0 features only on if they're available to avoid a crash on 3.x. Apple's got some documentation on this here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Overview/overview.html

Comment: One gotcha I discovered since: Add UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to the plist to opt out of iOS 4 fast switching until you can test it well.